# create div in jquery without using append

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

when i'll click input field div will create dynamic,only using input field.it is possible to create div without using append(attr) in jquery.i don't know please help me

```
<input type="text"  id="date_id" class="date" />
```

i'm expecting:

```
<input type="text"  id="date_id" class="date" />
 <div id="div_id"></div>
```

Comment: Look at other method like [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

Comment: Complete your code so we can help you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$("#date_id").after('<div id="div_id"></div>')
```

Comment: ok i'm using label field when i click input field that label will hide using after(attr)

Answer (score 0):

there is several method are available in ***Jquery*** to create dynamic element except ***.append()***, like

```
$("#elementId").after('<div id="div_id"></div>')// insert after the element

$("#elementId").before('<div id="div_id"></div>') // insert before the element

('<div id="div_id"></div>').appendTo($("#elementId")); // insert into the element
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.one()` to prevent duplicate `#div_id` elements in `document` , `.insertAdjacentHTML`

```js
$("#date_id").one("click", function() {
  this.insertAdjacentHTML("afterEnd", "<div id=div_id>div_id</div>")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<label>
  <input type="text" id="date_id" class="date" value="" />
</label>
```